# Transparent areas PVR textures loading white in cocos2d

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, textures, pvrtc

I'm loading a large number of PVR texures in cocos2d in an iOS app, but the transparent areas of the PVR textures are loading white.

I've created the textures using the command `texturetool -e PVRTC -o $file.pvr -f PVR $file`

The textures seem to show transparency when viewed in the TexturePacker app.

Is there something I need to set in cocos2d to make these work? Or do I need to run texturetool with different flags?

[image: Texture viewed in TexturePacker]

[image: Texture viewed in-app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe "premultiply alpha" helps. This is a checkbox in TexturePacker, found in the left pane at the bottom under "Advanced".

Hover over this checkbox to get more information. In particular you'll need to enable premultiplied alpha in cocos2d with

```
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
```

Comment: Boom. I think you nailed it.
It seems that the alpha on the edges of transparencies is a little rough for what we want to do. But thanks for the answer!